# Distributed transactions before ADO.NET 2.0

Tags: .net, ado.net

Now we can easily handle distributed transactions by System.Transactions assembly and TransactionScope class. But how were distributed transactions handled before ADO.NET 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the EnterpriseServices classes which interact with COM+.

[COM+ Integration: How .NET Enterprise Services Can Help You Build Distributed Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301491.aspx)

[HOW TO: Perform a Distributed Transaction with a .NET Provider by Using ServicedComponent in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316247)